# HTML input box with jQuery won't work in IE

Tags: jquery, html, eclipse, input

Here is the code. I've tried two versions of jQuery.  If I go with 10.2, I'll most likely add the library jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js  to add back in IE functionality.  This won't allow spaces to be entered into the input box anywhere, and if you paste in a string with spaces when you move off the spaces are taken out.  I CORRECTED THE CODE AND TOOK OUT THE EXTRA

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#UserName").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32)
      return false;
  },
  change: function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="UserName"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is an extra __<script>__ tag remove it first,,,

Comment: is that the behavior that you want, which is not happening in IE, or is that the behavior you're getting that you don't want? clarify please. Also, which version of IE?

Comment: IE 8.0.6 and 8.0.7 - now is seems to run, but when I am using Eclipse it doesn't work ... is that well known?

Comment: Pranav had the solution - simple typo, I panicked!